# How to simply introduce a short (2ns) delay on a line?

Tags: timing, delay

We found a race condition in one of our production circuits.

A CPLD chip acting as address decoder plus a couple other functions, receives address and data signal over two buses. A peripheral device has only one bus, and latches the value on the bus as address on falling edge of the ALE line, then as data on rising edge.

The CPLD outputs the contents of the address bus on high level of the ALE line, contents of the data bus on low ALE line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1U59x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Data sheets say the peripheral needs both the address and data state to be sustained for 2ns after receiving the ALE edge to latch them properly. Unfortunately, in some cases the decoder is faster, leading to the peripheral latching the lines when they are transitioning from address to data or vice versa.

Introducing a 2ns delay on the line to the decoder (while not affecting the signal to the peripheral) would resolve the issue.

The CPLD is filled to the brim so adding extra logic to it won't work, and since it's a part of a device already deployed, reworking everything is out of question (stuff like adding separate 'toggle' line from the CPU, driven separately from ALE) - we need a "hot fix", something small, simple and easy to add. So my question - how to easily introduce a delay of order of 2ns to a line like that? (specifically, not delaying it on the second branch, so that that the peripheral receives the signal 2ns before the decoder does.)

Comment: What's the range of delays needed? So if the tpd is 2 +/- x ns, what is x?

Comment: Cut the trace and add a series resistor and (if actually necessary) cap? A tinylogic buffer?  But what if someone else substitutes a faster cpld next year?

Comment: Does your layout have space to patch in an RC filter? Or could you just use the parasitic trace inductance with a capacitor near the peripheral ALE input?

Comment: @caveman: -0 +40ns - shouldn't be shorter but there's a plenty of wiggle room up.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The cap would delay the whole line including the peripheral input. The whole board needs to be reworked soon for new production, but for now we need a hotfix for existing deployments. It's about introducing a difference between the two inputs, not about delaying the whole line relative to the rest of the board. Yes, a buffer slow enough would surely work, but how do I find buffers "with minimum propagation delay no less than..."? Usually they guarantee the delay "no longer than..."

Comment: Note that I said a resistor across a cut gap in the trace and only possibly a cap.  The resistor would let the input capacitance and any added in parallel with that delay the undriven end *relative* to the driven end, which is what you want.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: That could work, though how should I go about finding the right size of that resistor?

Comment: Experiment. (Or look up the input capacitance and calculate RC). Consider twice what seems to make it work.  But as previously stated, I don't like relying on Component performance *limitation* like that.

Comment: Chris Stratton has the right idea. Let's say the input capacitance for the toggle line is 20 pF, including the trace leading to it from your cut. Then a 100 ohm will produce a time constant of 2 nsec. You need to analyze the relationship between the signal swing and the input threshold and determine the % of swing that is required to trigger your rising edge. Plug that into the standard RC response and you get a rough idea of what RC value you need. Then (and only then) you can play with it to give yourself some margin. And don't forget scope probe loading, either.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Combine your comments as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: 2 feet of cable would do the 2ns too

Comment: @PlasmaHH: In one hand, yes. On the other hand, the problem occurs primarily when external electromagnetic interference pulls the lines away from clean "0" or clean "1" reducing the time they need to switch from one state to the other... meaning extra 2 feet of antenna won't be too good for the system...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a spare non-inverting gate on the board and route the one signal through that first.  Or use two inverting gate in series.  Either of those methods should give a few nS of delay.

A small inductor delay line might work too, but you may inject some reflections.